# Renaming column in Android sqlite database results in error

Tags: mysql, android, sqlite

I've been modifying the [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) for Android very subtly- all I did was rename the column from `title` to `name`:

Before:

```
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
```

...

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title text not null, body text not null);";
```

After:

```
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
```

...

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "name text not null, body text not null);";
```

However,  it always results in this:

```
06-10 03:29:38.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.demo.notepad1/com.android.demo.notepad1.Notepadv1}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, body FROM notes
```

...

```
06-10 03:29:38.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(344): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
no such column: name: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, body FROM notes
```

Am I failing to rename something?  All I am modifying is the Exercise 1 Solution program from the Notepad tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Are you completely sure the db is being re-created?

I think uninstalling the app will remove the db.

Try running:

```
adb uninstall com.android.demo.notepad1
```

and then run your application again.

Comment: @Apophenia Overload: Try installing http://code.google.com/p/questoidsqlitemanager/ to check what you have inside your db.

Comment: You can use also use the adb shell and sqlite3 command to check the DB contents.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using adb.  There's nothing in the table.  I think the app is crashing before it can fill up the database with entries.

Answer (score 0):

name could be a reserved word ... try [name] in your query, or try a different name, something like name1 (just for testing to see if that's the reason).